# How can I make particles disappear on collision?

Tags: particles, collision

Nice to meet you, everyone. I am a Japanese blender beginner.

https://youtu.be/72IxWn3J9zg?t=6

As in the above video, I would like to express that when the ozone particles collide with the virus particles, the ozone will erase the virus.
**However, particles cannot be controlled individually.**
Therefore, I am having trouble controlling the timing at which the particles disappear.

If anyone knows a tutorial video or article that can solve this problem please let me know.

I'm really sorry for my poor English.
Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: hello and welcome! can you provide more details and some screenshots of what you have already tried.

Comment: Also please make the title more explicit on your problem

Comment: Welcome @user152399!  I edited this question's title to better describe the problem.  If I was mistaken, please feel free to edit the title yourself.  I felt that the old title information was contained in the question, so I didn't repeat it there.

Comment: Particles can be killed when they hit a collision object & dead emitter particles disappear by default. But unfortunately, there is no collision detection between particles. Maybe the *Boids* physics of the particle system works for you. With this physics type, you can make the ozone particles fight the virus particles. If their health goes down they die and disappear. Here is an example: https://imgur.com/a/TkulHRq I made the hunters fairly aggressive. Dead particles can be visualized in a different color/shape with 2 *Particle Instance* modifiers if needed (1 for dead, 1 for alive particles)